# Caves for Unreal Engine - convenient workflow

Tags: workflow, procedural, unreal-engine, retopology, remesh

I'm doing a caves for my terrain. I have 2 solution, but none are good enough
*Caves are just a simple shapes - later I'm going to improve*

**The problem is - to merge a landscape and a caves**
Solution I know are
• using UE's Landscape System
• and without

### **Single-mesh terrain**

Caves - via mesh boolean

[image]

+clean merge line
+simple workflow
-is not compatible with UE Landscape System

### **UE Landscape using Visibility Mask**

It also affects collision (is enterable hole)
Caves are sepatate mesh

[image] [image]

+UE Landscape System
-merge line are awful

I do not like solution - to fill a gaps using other meshes

The main reason I want, I use Landscape - is a **splatmap** (landscape material data).
**Sediment and flow maps - for a foliage actor distribution**
[image]

Ideally, I'm looking for solution - I can use UE Landscape

Otherwise, looking for splatmap implementation in Blender